# Conditional handler in integration flow

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I'm developing web hook notification service that allows  clients to subscribe/unsubscribe to messages flowing through middle-ware and get notified about the messages (according to provided criteria) by posting the message payload to provided callback URL.
The message delivery looks like this :

```
flowBuilder
    .enrichHeaders(e->e.header(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,true))
    .handle(Http.outboundChannelAdapter(message-> {
              String subscriptionId = message.getHeaders().get(SUBSCRIPTION_ID_HEADER_NAME, String.class);
                return subscriptionsStore.get(UUID.fromString(subscriptionId)).getCallbackUrl(); //potential NPE if subscription was removed 

            },restTemplateBuilder.build())

.get()
```

As you can see, the implementation of **uriFunction** fetches the callback URL from `subscriptionsStore` by subscription id(part of the message header).

My question is about the situation where the client has already unsubscribed with  his subscription id and I'm after the conditional handler.

I know that I can filter messages with subscription id are still present in subscription store, but this is not the proper solution, as client might unsubscribe between `filter` and `handle`  operations still causing NRE in `uriFunction`.

Another solution is to enreach the header with callback URL and filter then by header having non-empty value, but I don't want to compromise neither header nor payload of original message.

I can think about another approach: to calculate the URI of non-existing subscriptions as some static value and add  interceptor to `RestTempalte` to simulate the HTTP OK replay for this specific URI value...

So my question is about the proper way to handle this case by using the standard EIP or another Spring integration  feature I'm not aware about...

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I've added the `DedicatedMessage` class that holds the context :

```
public static class DedicatedMessage  extends GenericMessage<Object> implements MessageDecorator{
        @Getter
        @Transient
        private Subscription subscription;


        public DedicatedMessage(Subscription subscription,Object payload,Map<String,Object> headers) {
            super(payload,headers);
            this.subscription = subscription;
        }

        @Override
        public Message<?> decorateMessage(Message<?> message) {
            return new DedicatedMessage (subscription,message.getPayload(),message.getHeaders());
        }
    }
```

and changed the flow as :

```
flowBuilder
   .enrichHeaders(e->e.header(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,true))
  .handle((payload, headers) -> {
                        String subscriptionId = (String) headers.get(SUBSCRIPTION_ID_HEADER_NAME);
                        Subscription subscription = subscriptionsCache.get(UUID.fromString(subscriptionId));
                        return Optional.ofNullable(subscription)
                                .map(s->  new DedicatedMessage(s, payload,headers))
                                .orElse(null);
                    })
  .handle(Http.outboundChannelAdapter(message->((DedicatedMessage)message).getSubscription().getCallbackUrl()
                            ,restTemplateBuilder.build())
.get()
```

Any issues with this apporach ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what your `NRE` abbreviation means, but you could throw a `NoSuchSubscriptionException` from your `subscriptionsStore.get()` method and then ignore/report that exception in an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` applied to the outbound channel adapter in its `endpoint.advice()` chain.

Comment: Null Reference Exception, sorry, should have been NPE, thrown when subscriptionStore.get(id) returns null. I'll try to apply advice and handle the exception there

Comment: You need to wrap the `get()` and throw the exception if it returns `null`.

Comment: Yes, sure, I'll try your advice tomorrow. But don't you think that conditional handler might be the  candidate to include in spring integration?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean - as you say, if we add a condition, there is still a race condition in that the subscription could be removed between the test for the condition and the handler invocation. It just shortens the time window over using a filter, but doesn't eliminate it.

Comment: Well, the conditional handler could be a bit smarter by providing the 'context' to the wrapped handler: context=getContext(message) ;if(test the context)  {targetHandler.handle(message, context)}...

Comment: I understand that this will require handler API changes, but context might be passed via thread local for example

Comment: I've updated my question with another possible solution, are there any pitfalls there ?